# ODBC Connection Import Tables to MS Access fails with "Cannot define field more than once"

Tags: mysql, ms-access

I need to create an Access database from an existing mySQL database. I was able to import some of the tables using the ODBC connection but a few of the tables were erroring out saying 'Cannot define field more than once'. I couldn't figure out why I was getting that error (There are no fields with duplicate names in any of the failing tables, nor any fields with special characters).  Is there anywhere to look to find out more information about why these tables are failing?  Here is a screenshot of the data in one of the failing tables:

[image]

And the schema:

[image]

I thought maybe it was the field named 'Year' since that's a function in Access, but there's another table without a year field that's failing.  That table had too many fields for a screenshot but here is the list of fields in that table:

PlotID

State
StudySite
Watershed
Elevation
ElevationModifier
Aspect
Locale
Directions
OwnershipStatus
OwnerContactInfo
DendrobandInstall
PaintTrees
CoreTrees
BiophysicalRegion
ForestType
Comments
Origin
HavePermission

Any ideas on how to import these failing tables?  I tried exporting the create table SQL but I couldn't figure out how to get the exported SQL to play nice in MS Access.  I've spent 10+ hours on this and it's ridiculous!  Unfortunately I can't change any of the existing field names.

Thanks!

Comment: Is this a one-time effort? How many tables fail? How many records? Could you just manually build Access table(s) and copy/paste records?

Comment: This will be an annual effort.  There are 8 tables that failed and anywhere from 4000 to 32000 records per table.  Some of the tables have around 20 fields.  I guess I've already spent 10 hours trying to figure this out, so maybe another 10 manually rebuilding the database is better than spinning my wheels on this error? I don't know.

Comment: I manually created one of the tables but when I try to get the data from one to the other either by sql insert into statement or just copy/paste I get the error "The text is too long to be edited" in MS Access.  So will I have to take the 32000 record table and copy/paste in small chunks?  This seems absolutely insane!

Comment: Maybe and yes it does. Just to confirm, try doing INSERT SELECT filtered to one record.

Answer (score 0):

just had the same issue. I finally figured out my problem is that I have 2 tables with the same table name in different schemas in mySQL. So I dropped the useless schema and redo the connection, and it worked.

For example:
I want to connect a schema named *share* to access, and the schema *share* has a table named *visits*. And in my SQL, I have another schema named *trouble*, which also has a table named *visits*. When I try to connect schema *share* to access, the software cannot figure out which table named visits to be connected to (share.visits vs. trouble.visits).

Hope this helps. Good luck!